# Understanding Theorem 9.19 in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$L(R^n,R^m)$ is the set of all linear transformations from $R^n$ to $R^m.$ For $A\in L(R^n,R^m),$ we define the norm $\|A\|$ of $A$ to be the $\sup$ of all numbers $|A\mathbf{x}|,$ where $\mathbf{x}$ ranges over all vectors in $R^n$ with $\left|\mathbf{x}\right|\le 1.$

It can be shown that

If $A\in L(R^n,R^m)$ and $B\in L(R^m,R^k),$ then $$\|BA\|\le\|B\|\|A\|.\tag{1}$$

> So now suppose $\mathbf{A}\in L(R,R^n)$ then 
>   \begin{align}
> \|\mathbf{A}\| &=\sup \{\left|\mathbf{A}(x)\right|: |x|\le 1\}\\
> &=\sup \{\left|\mathbf{A}(1\cdot x)\right|: |x|\le 1\}\\
> &=\sup \{\left|x\cdot  \mathbf{A}(1)\right| : |x|\le 1\}\\
> &=\sup\{\left|\mathbf{A}(1)\right|\}\\
> &= |\mathbf{A}(1)|. \tag{2}
> \end{align}

Following is theorem $9.19$ from Baby Rudin :

[image]

> **EDIT**: I think the way I had asked the question earlier was quite confusing and hence the edit. Let me rephrase what's been bothering me :
>
> $\bullet$ If $\mathbf{g'}(t) \in L(R,R^m) $ then why does Rudin write $\left|\mathbf{g'}(t)\right|$ instead of $\|\mathbf{g'}(t)\|$? Did he mean to say $\left|\mathbf{g'}(t)(\mathbf{x})\right|$?
>
> $\bullet$ Similarly $\gamma '(t)= \mathbf{(b-a)}$ is in $L(R,R^n),$ again the interchange of $||$ and $\|\|$ is confusing!

As of now, this is how I made sense of it :

Assuiming $\left|\mathbf{g'}(t)\right| = \left|\mathbf{g'}(t)(x)\right|$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and $\gamma '(t)$ is the linear transformation which maps $x\in [0,1]$ to the vector $x\mathbf{(b-a)}$ in $R^n$

Since $x\in [0,1]$ we have $\left|\mathbf{g'}(t)(x)\right|\le \|\mathbf{g'}(t)\|.$ Also $\|\mathbf{b-a}\|=\underbrace{\left|\mathbf{(b-a)}(1)\right|}_{\text{using } (2)}=\left|\mathbf{b-a}\right|$ Thus $$\left|\mathbf{g'}(t)(x)\right|\le \|\mathbf{g'}(t)\|=\|\mathbf{f'}(\gamma (t))\mathbf{(b-a)}\|\le\|\mathbf{f'}(\gamma (t))\|\cdot\|\mathbf{(b-a)}\|=\|\mathbf{f'}(\gamma (t))\|\cdot\left|\mathbf{b-a}\right|.$$ and finally

$$\left|\mathbf{g'}(t)(x)\right|\le \|\mathbf{f'}(\gamma (t))\|\cdot\left|\mathbf{b-a}\right|.$$

> Have I done it right?

Comment: No, $b-a\in\Bbb R^n$, not $L(R,R)$. And $g$ is a map from $\Bbb R$ to itself, so he just proved that ||g'(t)||=|g'(t)(1)|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you! I have edited the question. Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Also why would you say $b-a$ is in $R^n$? Isn't $b-a = \gamma '(t)$ which is in $L(R,R^n).$

Comment: $\mathbf{g}'(t)$ is in $L(R,R^n)$. The first pink highlighted part is not being used in the part you are struggling with, $b-a$ is not being considered a linear transformation here either.

Comment: Also $\gamma(t)$ parameterizes $b-a$, it is not equal to $b-a$. I always try to advise people new to real analysis to steer clear of this book.

Comment: @DavidReed  Why is $\mathbf{g}'(t)$ in $L(R,R^n)$ when $\mathbf{g}(t)$ is a function from $R$ to $R$?

Comment: @BijeshK.S Actually it is R^m and not R^n reading closer. It is because $\mathbf{g}(t)$ is. In particular $\gamma : R \to R^n$ and $\mathbf{f}:R^n \to R^m$ so the composition $\mathbf{g}(t)=(\mathbf{f}\circ \gamma)(t): R \to R^m$

Comment: Domain of $\gamma $ and $\mathbf{g'}(t)$ is $[0,1]$ and thus we have $\left|\mathbf{g'}(t)(x)\right|\le \|\mathbf{g'}(t)\|.$ Also $\|\mathbf{b-a}\|=\left|\mathbf{(b-a)}(1)\right|=\left|\mathbf{b-a}\right|$ Thus $$\left|\mathbf{g'}(t)(x)\right|\le \|\mathbf{g'}(t)\|=\|\mathbf{f'}(\gamma (t))\mathbf{(b-a)}\|\le\|\mathbf{f'}(\gamma (t))\|\cdot\|\mathbf{(b-a)}\|=\|\mathbf{f'}(\gamma (t))\|\cdot\left|\mathbf{b-a}\right|.$$ and finally 

$$\left|\mathbf{g'}(t)(x)\right|\le \|\mathbf{f'}(\gamma (t))\|\cdot\left|\mathbf{b-a}\right|.$$

Comment: @DavidReed Is this the right interpretation?

Comment: @BijeshK.S No. I have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The operator norm he gives satisfies the following:

$$\vert T(x)\vert \leq \Vert T \Vert \, \vert x \vert \quad \text{for all }x$$

$\mathbf{b-a}$ is just a vector and is not a linear transformation here.

Let $T(\mathbf{x}):=\mathbf{f}'(\gamma(t)) \mathbf{\cdot x} $. The dot there refers to the dot product.

Now we have $|\mathbf{g}'(t)| = |\mathbf{f}'(\gamma(t))\, \cdot \mathbf{b-a}| = |T(\mathbf{b-a})| \leq \Vert T \Vert \, |\mathbf{b-a}| = \Vert \mathbf{f}'(\gamma(t)\Vert \, |\mathbf{b-a}|$

Comment: What is the domain of $T$? $R^n$?

Comment: If $\mathbf{f}$ is a function from $R^n$ to $R^m,$ then $\mathbf{f'}(p)$ will be a linear transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m.$ So, the way $T$ is defined ; does it make any sense to talk about the dot product of a linear transformation with a vector?

Comment: @BijeshK.S  .$\mathbf{f}'(t)$ is not (necessarily) a linear transformation, the mapping $ x \to \mathbf{f}'(t) \cdot x$ is, and that is what is meant when one speaks of the derivative being a linear transformation. Just think on R, f(x) = x, then f'(0)= 1, which can't be a linear transformation since a linear transformation must send 0 to 0